# Where should I start learning Landau's theory of superfluidity?

Tags: condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, superfluidity

Where should I start learning Landau's theory of superfluidity?

For a second year undergraduate.

Answer (score 1):

- [Collected Papers of L.D. Landau edited by D. Ter Haar](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=epc4BQAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false)
- [The Discovery of Super Fluidity](http://www.lps.ens.fr/~balibar/JLTP-History.pdf)

These above books might help you. Start doing your own research, this is how we study.